# Make waypoint fire when bottom of element scrolls up into view

Tags: jquery, offset, jquery-waypoints

What if I want a waypoint to fire as soon as an element scrolls *up* into view? I have one waypoint happening when you scroll down. That works fine. But I want the other waypoint to fire as soon as the element scrolls back up into view (top of element at bottom of screen).

```
$(".picture").waypoint(function(direction){
            var $this = $(this);
            if (direction === "down") {
                setTimeout(function()
                    {
                        $this.children('.cutline_background').animate({"left":"0px"},2500, function(){});
                        $this.children('.text').animate({"left":"40px"},2500, function(){});
                    }, 3000);

            } 
    }, {offset: 0 });
    $(".picture").waypoint(function(direction){
            var $this = $(this);
            if (direction === "up") {
                $this.children('.cutline_background').css("left", "-20%");  
                $this.children('.text').css("left", "-20%");

            } 
    }, {offset: '90%' }); //this doesn't seem to be working
```

Comment: Here, I've created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ru9tndez/) with your approach - what is not OK?

Comment: I guess it appears as if it's not working with my website. Maybe there's another reason for that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Waypoints has an offset alias for this: `bottom-in-view`

```
$('.thing').waypoint(function(direction) {
  // do things
}, {
  offset: 'bottom-in-view'
})
```